# Uploading Office.File to server in Excel Add-in

Tags: office-js, fetch-api, office-addins

I'm working on an Excel Add-in using the Office.js library, and I'm encountering difficulties while trying to upload an Office.File object obtained from Office.context.document.getFileAsync to a web-server. I want to upload this file to a server using a fetch request.

I'm encountering Type errors when trying to use the Office.File object in a fetch request's body that want me to convert the Office.File to a blob, however I have found little-to-no documentation how to do so.

Has anyone been able to achieve this?

```
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(
      Office.FileType.Compressed, // Specify the file type
      async (result) => {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
          let fileSlice = result.value;
          if (fileSlice) {
            // Create the headers for the fetch request
            var myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append("ID", "4280");
            myHeaders.append("File", "test.xlsx");
            myHeaders.append("SubDir", "Postman");
            myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            myHeaders.append("SID", sessionID);

            const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
              method: "POST",
              headers: myHeaders,
              body: fileSlice,
              redirect: "follow",
            };

            fileSlice.closeAsync();

            // Perform the fetch request
            try {
              const response = await fetch(`${domain}/upload`, requestOptions);
              const result = await response.text();
              console.log(result);
            } catch (error) {
              console.log("error", error);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: "encountering difficulties" <--- elaborate. "Type errors" <-- which errors